# Iteration in Handles bar template

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have multiple template files. What I am trying to achieve is to iterate over the properties of a model which is associated with a different view. For example I have a model for messages like this

```
Cards.Message = DS.Model.extend({
   message: DS.attr('string'),
   font_size: DS.attr('string'),
   font_face: DS.attr('string'),
   text_color: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Now I am in another template which is recipient. So its controller is Recipient controller and the model associated with it is recipient. But I want to access the values of Message model here. So I am trying to do something like this here.

```
{{#each item in message}}
        {{item.message}}
{{/each}}
```

But nothing is being displayed here. I think we have to tell the handles bar template that we want to access the property of different model but how can we do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add the MessageController to the RecipientController by adding it through the [needs property](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/), like this:

```
App.RecipientController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs:['message'];
});
```

You'll then be able to access the properties of the message controller with a path like this: `controllers.message.model`.

This won't cause your messages to load though.  You'll still need to make sure they're loaded in the route.